# prevent bootstrap modal from opening when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with several bootstrap modals with:

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-12345"
```

The problem is, I have an entire table row that is clickable, like

```
<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-12345">
```

The modal content is in another hidden table row right below, followed by the next clickable row and so on. Now, this row also contains a button that will go to another page when clicked.

I need the entire row clickable so it opens the modal, except when the button to go to the other page is clicked, then I need to stop the modal from opening.

I need something like this

```
<script>
$('.ID').on('click', '.btn', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); })
</script>
```

But targeting this:

```
data-toggle="modal"
```

I also tried giving the TR a class of "modaltoggle" and then calling it with the javascript as .modaltoggle but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add some kind of identifier for the item you don't want to trigger the modal, a class like `no-modal` for example, then in your jQuery add code for the modal's `show.bs.modal` event. Capture the relatedElement, which is the element that triggered the event, then see if it has the class you're looking for. If it does, run `e.stopPropagation()`.

[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/6XGuXhP7St)

**jQuery**:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  var button = e.relatedTarget;
  if($(button).hasClass('no-modal')) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }  
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg no-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the second button has a class called `no-modal`. When clicked, the jQuery checks for the existence of that class, and if it exists it prevents the modal from popping. Clicking the first button causes the modal to pop normally because it doesn't have that class.

Bootstrap modals trigger specific events when they're popped by an element on the page, from the moment they're triggered through the moment they've fully popped. You can read about these events to get an idea of what you can use them for by checking the [Events section](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) for Bootstrap modals in the official documentation.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It only "works" because stopPropegation is undefined, which stops execution. The correct call is stopPropagation with an "a" instead of an e, but I tried it; the stopPropagation by itself is not effective in keeping the dialog from appearing. In fact, AoN's solution is closer. I am not sure why it was down voted because the "return false;" indeed properly stops execution and the dialog from appearing.

If  you were to add the return false; to your event handler following stopPropagation, it would work fine. (In fact, it works even without the stopPropagation call.)

Comment: Yeah, I tried this too--same scenario with a row and a button in one of the cells.  e always refers to the row, not the button.

Comment: I tried  e.stopPropegation(); and it didn't work for me. I used e.preventDefault();   e.stopImmediatePropagation(); and worked.

Comment: You have a typo there, stopPropegation should be stopPropagation

Comment: In Bootstrap 3 only `e.preventDefault();` or `return false;` works correctly. But note that if you have handler that adds modal's id into url hash before it opens than you may need to remove it first (`location.hash=''; return false;`) otherwise nothing will work.

Answer (score 18):

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
 return e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

OR

```
<button type="button" class="custom" data-toggle="modal" data-target-custom="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>
<script>
target = $(".custom").attr('data-target-custom');
if(condition) {
 $(target).modal('show');
}
</script>
```

e.stopPropagation(); or e.preventDefault(); it will not work if you going reopen modal or if multiple modal used in your page.

Comment: *Code snippet with some explanation is a great combination !!*

Comment: e.preventDefault is not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047300/e-preventdefault-is-not-working-while-openning-a-modal-after-changing-modal-text]

Comment: Upvoted because of comment "e.stopPropagation() or e.preventDefault() will not work if you are going to reopen the modal."  In my use case, where modals are re-used, this was an issue.  Instead `return false` did the trick. (BS 4.6)

Comment: The issue of reopening the modal appears to be because of a bug in BS4:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67521199

Answer (score 15):

Here's a JSFiddle to demo what I'm about to explain: http://jsfiddle.net/68y4zb3g/

As MattD explained and demonstrated, preventing a modal from launching is fairly easy, though his example applies to standard modal application.  Since you use the `.btn` in your script code, I assume you applied it to all your buttons in question.  I've also assumed that you kept the modal code similar to that on the Bootstrap demo page.  If you provide your actual table code, I can tailor it specifically to what you already have.

```js
$('tr .btn').on('click', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
td {
    border: 1px #000000 solid;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-12345">
        <td>Launch modal 12345</td>
        <td><button id="btn-12345" class="btn">12345</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="modal fade" id="modal-12345" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        12345
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note: I substituted the `DIV` that would normally act as the outer wrapper of the modal for the `TD` and added a tidbit of CSS to make it a little easier to see the separation in content.

By using a class that is applied to all the buttons, you don't have to write a function for every single ID.  Having said that, I recommend using a custom class  as your trigger.  `.btn` is a standard class within the core of Bootstrap, so try using `.modalBtn`, to prevent any potential for conflict with legitimate Bootstrap functionality.

Hope this helps. ^^

Comment: This answer is the more correct answer and deserves to be marked as the solution. My only comment is that it is a bit more than the OP asked for. Perhaps it was down voted because of its partial irrelevance.

Comment: I'm trying to use this solution for myself as well. Once the modal is prevented once, it won't open again. I'm performing a little validation before opening the modal, if validation fails, I don't want the modal to open. I want to alert the user to the error, once they fix the error the modal should be able to open.

Comment: @BrentConnor Good catch. I honestly hadn't spotted that. I've revised the script to account for that by having it ignore the click on the `TR` instead of trying to prevent the launch of the `.modal`.

Comment: @AoN could you help me out with [my question too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506716/javascript-toggle-modal-show-after-validation)?

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove following line from your code:

   data-toggle = "modal"

Then, in your function once your validation is done, write following code:

```
$('#myModal').modal({
   show: true
});
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: MODAL: Option "show" provided type "string" but expected type "boolean". 
 Perhaps this should be without the surrounding`''`.

Comment: I just confirmed my previous comment, and it is really without the `''`. Fixed it for you.