# JavaScript toggle modal show after validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

I'm submitting a form through a modal. Based on user input, some data will need sent to the modal. I need to validate the data before loading the modal. The current code prevents showing the modal if no orders are selected, but once the user selects some orders and resubmits the form, the modal still doesn't show.

JS

```
function batchHoldModalLauncher($hold_name){

// get modal id
var modal_id = "#"+$hold_name+"_modal_id";

// check if any orders are selected
if ($("#order_hold_table_body input:checkbox:checked").length > 0)
{
    $(modal_id).modal('show');
}
else
{
    // no boxes checked
    $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
        return false;
    });

    alert('Choose some orders to put on hold');
}
}
```

Laravel PHP Code where form is submitted and modal is called

```
<div class="col-md-3" style="margin-top: 20px;">
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/hold', 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'form-inline']) !!}
<h4>
    Orders for Batch {{ $batch->id }}
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Hold <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-danger">
            @foreach($holds as $hold)
                <?php $hold_name = str_replace(' ', '', $hold->name); ?>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" onclick="batchHoldModalLauncher('{{ $hold_name  }}')"
                       data-target="#modal{{ $hold_name }}">{{ $hold->name }}</a></li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
</h4>
<!-- Show each order in batch and allow user to place orders on hold -->
<table class="table table-striped" id="order_hold_table">
    <thead>
    <th>Order Number</th>
    <th>Hold
        <!-- de/select all checkboxes -->
        {!! Form::checkbox('hold_toggle', null, false, [
            'class'=>'toggle-button',
            'style'=>'float:right'
        ]) !!}</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="order_hold_table_body">
    @foreach($orders as $o)
        <tr>
            <td>
                @if($type == 'receiving')
                    {{ $o->id }}
                @elseif($type == 'sales')
                    {{ $o->order_number }}
                @endif
            </td>
            <td>
                {!! Form::checkbox('hold[]', $o->id, false, ['style'=>'float:right']) !!}
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: any errors on your browser console ?

Comment: No errors in console.

Comment: Try `console.log($hold_name)` and `console.log($("#order_hold_table_body input:checkbox:checked").length)` and see if you get what you expect.

Comment: Both commands return the expected output.

Comment: `if` block is already functioning as expected. Just tested with console.log statements.

Comment: When the form is resubmitted with orders selected, do you still get the alert, or do you just get 'nothing'. So does it fulfill the if statement?

Comment: Still get the alert when form is resubmitted.

Comment: DO you maybe have a fiddle? Because I understand that, when a checkbox is selected, in the console the length property returns something > 0?

Comment: I'm trying to get a fiddle working now.

Comment: @Rik I misunderstood your question. When form is resubmitted with orders I get nothing on the page, but `console.log` statements still work correctly.

Comment: In JavaScript I just changed `$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() { return false;  });` to `$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });` and the behavior is the same.

Comment: I think the event is called `shown.bs.modal` (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) Note the n, after show

Comment: Does it work when you submit it the form with a row checked the first time. I don't see the html where you are actually declaring your modal (Did you leave it out the snippet? Our is it not on your page? I would also advise you to have one modal, and fill it with the correct data in your `on('shown.bs.modal', function(e){...})` especially if you are retrieving data via a post, and not ajax.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94134/discussion-between-rik-and-brent-connor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BrentConnor, Per your message in the chat, I'm posting your solution as an answer.

It appears that you had been using the original code I had provided in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27868091/3869056 to stop your modals from opening when a particular action occurs, even if that action inherently is consider a valid trigger. As you pointed out with my answer, it actually broke the ability to open modals.

Rather than returning `false` for the action, you should `stopPropagation()` of the parent while targeting the child for testing if it meets the requirements for preventing the launch of the modal.

```
$('.modal_launcher').click(function(e) {
    // check if any orders are selected
    if($("#order_hold_table_body input:checkbox:checked").length > 0) {
        // append order numbers to the appropriate hold modal
    } else {
        // no orders selected -> alert user & prevent modal.
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('Choose some orders to put on hold');
    }
}
```

I'm sorry I couldn't have been a bit more active in helping you to sort it out, but I'm glad my advice led you to the solution. :)