# e.preventDefault is not working while openning A modal after changing modal-text. modal is openning without changing content

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to change the modal-body text when modal trigger button is clicked . The modal is opening but the modal-body text is not changing.
This is the code for modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info open-modal" data-remote="false" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal">Register</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Then source for preventing default event

```
$('.open-modal').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('hello i am jquery');
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

**Why alert('hello i am jquery'); line is not executing  ?**

Comment: When I run your code as a codepen, it works fine: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PpdbrJ

Comment: Yess . But this code is not working at mine pc .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may happen when your HTML takes precedence over jquery since your button specifes the target modal to open with the following attributes

```
data-remote="false" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal"
```

Remove those and then the jquery will be fine

```js
$('.open-modal').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('hello i am jquery');
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info open-modal" >Register</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To trigger a modal to show programmatically, you can use the following:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

You can also have an event handler being triggered and add your code in there:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function() {
    alert('hello i am jquery');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case: Below code worked properly if the case fails:

```
$('#myModal').modal({show: 'false'});
```