# how to use keypress event.preventDefault in modal form ? jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

i've to use barcode reader, and the problem is when i show a barcode it saves by default, i tried this to prevent it, but it seems doesnt work for modal form

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".inputs_imei").keypress(function(event){
            if (event.which == '15') {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
        
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <input type="number" c

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
class="inputs_imei">
              <input type="number" class="inputs_imei">
              <input type="number" class="inputs_imei">
              <input type="number" class="inputs_imei">
              <input type="number" class="inputs_imei">
              <input type="number" class="inputs_imei">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

it work for the other un modal fields, but for the modal inputs dont work! and act like save button every time that i try to input a number from the barcode reader ?
thank you in advance ..

Comment: No idea if that will help or not. You definitely need to explain the problem with more detail though

Comment: @charlietfl when i use barcode reader outside of the the modal form, without this action `keypress` it will automatically works as submit button! but with adding the `keypress` add detecting the numbers of the barcode which is 15 length, it prevent that action, but this method doesnt work for modal input form

Comment: Maybe this post will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047300/e-preventdefault-is-not-working-while-openning-a-modal-after-changing-modal-text