# Using datatables prevent other modal from opening when clicked on a button inside a tr td where clicking on tr opens another modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-modal

So I have a web page which has a table. I have linked each tr to open a modal showing details.

In the last column I have some button to perform specific task for example edit.

I have referred to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867304/prevent-bootstrap-modal-from-opening-when-a-button-is-clicked) and achieved some level or functionality. My button does open the correct modal but when i click outside or I click on the input elements of the modal or the close button, the modal linked to tr opens up.

Can someone help me fix it so that when I click the button only the modal linked to it opens up and functions properly, as in, it takes input and closes properly instead of opening the modal linked to tr?

The edit button opens the correct modal. But if I click anywhere on the modal it closes and opens the modal linked to the tr by the anchor button.

What I want is **modalBtn** to open the modal linked to it with everything working correctly. If I close that modal the modal linked to tr shouldn't open. Basically I want two modals in this scenario. One which opens when i click anywhere on the tr, one modal to open when i click on the edit button which is inside tr in that last column.
Please simplify your answer as much as possible thanks.

To clarify my original question:
I am able to apply my function to all tr tags. The question is I have a last column which has buttons in it. 2 of those buttons are linked to their own unique modals. When I click anywhere in tr the correct modal is opened. Also when I click on button the correct modal open. Problem arises here, when i click anywhere on the screen even the current modal input element the current modal closes and opens the **modal linked to tr tag which functions normally**. What I want is that every modal works normally.

I have modified the code so you can simply run the html and check the problem this is not the original table just a small example of my problem.

First part of my problem was solved by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77166403/6088792) answer. Second part is how to do the same functionality when using it with datatables. Currently when I click on the column header for sort, after sorting the click on tr element doesn't open the modal linked to it.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  Array.from($('tr[id*="Deets"]')).forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('modalBtn')) {
        e.stopPropagation()
      } else {
        document.querySelector(`#anchor${element.id.split('Deets')[1]}`).click()
      }
    })
  });
  Array.from($('td .modalBtn')).forEach(ele => {
    console.log(ele);
    ele.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      console.log(e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.getAttribute('id'));
      $(`#${e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.getAttribute('id')}`).modal('show');
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@latest/dist/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@latest" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table class="table table-borderless datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="w-30">Remarks</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="demoDeets1">
                <td scope="row"><label for="" title="remark">remark</label>
                </td>
                <td scope="row">
                    <a class="icon-3 modalBtn">
                        Edit
                    </a>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="edit1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <b>
                                        heading1
                                    </b>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                        aria-label="Close"></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <input type="text" class="big-input-w13h4 form-control" name="mail">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <a id="anchor1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#demoDeets1"></a>
            <div class="modal fade" id="demoDeets1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <b>
                                heading
                            </b>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <div class="col-lg-12">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <tr id="demoDeets2">
                <td scope="row"><label for="" title="remark">remark</label>
                </td>
                <td scope="row">
                    <a class="icon-3 modalBtn">
                        Edit
                    </a>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="edit2" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <b>
                                        heading1
                                    </b>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                        aria-label="Close"></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <input type="text" class="big-input-w13h4 form-control" name="mail">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <a id="anchor2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#demoDeets2"></a>
            <div class="modal fade" id="demoDeets2" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <b>
                                heading
                            </b>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <div class="col-lg-12">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <tr id="demoDeets3">
                <td scope="row"><label for="" title="remark">remark</label>
                </td>
                <td scope="row">
                    <a class="icon-3 modalBtn">
                        Edit
                    </a>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="edit3" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">

                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <b>
                                        heading1
                                    </b>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                        aria-label="Close"></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <input type="text" class="big-input-w13h4 form-control" name="mail">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <a id="anchor1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#demoDeets3"></a>
            <div class="modal fade" id="demoDeets3" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <b>
                                heading
                            </b>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <div class="col-lg-12">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**datatables code:**

```js
$(() => {
  const dataTable = new simpleDatatables.DataTable(".datatable");
  $('.table').on('click', 'tr[data-target*="Deets"] td', function (e) {
    if ($(this).find('.modalBtn').length === 0) {
      const target = $(this).closest("tr").data("target");
      $(target).modal("show");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@latest/dist/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@latest" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-borderless datatable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="w-30">Remarks</th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-target="#demoDeets1">
        <td scope="row"><label for="" title="remark">Remark 1</label>
        </td>
        <td scope="row">
          <a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit1" class="icon-3 modalBtn">Edit</a>
          <div class="modal fade" id="edit1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <b>heading1</b>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <input type="text" class="big-input-w13h4 form-control" name="mail">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-target="#demoDeets2">
        <td scope="row"><label for="" title="remark">Remark 2</label>
        </td>
        <td scope="row">
          <a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit2" class="icon-3 modalBtn">Edit</a>

          <div class="modal fade" id="edit2" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <b>heading2</b>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <input type="text" class="big-input-w13h4 form-control" name="mail">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr data-target="#demoDeets3">
        <td scope="row"><label for="" title="remark">Remark 3</label>
        </td>
        <td scope="row">
          <a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit3" class="icon-3 modalBtn">Edit</a>

          <div class="modal fade" id="edit3" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <b>heading3</b>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <input type="text" class="big-input-w13h4 form-control" name="mail">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="modal fade" id="demoDeets1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <b>heading row modal 1</b>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="demoDeets2" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <b>heading row modal 2</b>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="demoDeets3" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <b>heading rwo modal 3</b>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This does not look like a DJANGO issue. I made you a snippet. Please click [edit] and add relevant bootstrap and change the HTML to RENDERED HTML without server code

Comment: Also why not `$('td .modalBtn')).on('click', function()`

Comment: Also I try to figure out what your script is doing. It could be this: `$('tr[id*="Deets"]').on('click', function() { let $btn = $(this).find('.modalBtn'); if ($btn) $btn.trigger('click'); });`

Comment: no its not an django issue. its a js issue. there is no css in effect. I have edited it so there are no django tags in it.

Comment: So remove the DJANGO templated code and replace it with rendered HTML

Comment: I have done it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255389/discussion-between-indrajeet-singh-yadav-and-mplungjan).

Comment: Will this ```$('tr[id*="Deets"]').on('click', function() { let $btn = $(this).find('.modalBtn'); if ($btn) $btn.trigger('click'); });```, work with all the tr which will be rendered once the page is loaded. because there will be atleast 10 such rows. I have added 3 rows and removed images from anchor to keep it simple I hope it helps.

Comment: You would want to delegate. `$("table tbody").on("click",'tr[id*="Deets"]',function() {....})` which will handle anything added to the tbody at any time - including AFTER the page has rendered  - so if you insert rows they will be handled too

Comment: @mplungjan that's not my problem. I am able to apply my function to all tr tags. The question is I have a last column which has buttons in it. 2 of those buttons are linked to their own unique modals. When I click anywhere in tr the correct modal is opened. Also when I click on button the correct modal open. Problem arises here, when i click anywhere on the screen even the modal input element the current modal closes and opens the modal linked to tr tag.

Comment: Please update the snippet to a [mcve] I cannot open any modals in the example given

Comment: @mplungjan did you load bootstrap? I have those as files and not link.

Comment: @mplungjan I have updated the code I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is far too complex and your HTML was invalid.

Here is a better version since your button is in its own td

```js
$(() => {
  let table = new DataTable('.table');
  $('.table').on('click', 'tr[data-target*="Deets"] td', function(e) { // listen for clicks in cells
    if ($(this).find('.modalBtn').length === 0) { // only react if there is not a button
      const target = $(this).closest("tr").data("target"); // get the data-target from row
      $(target).modal("show"); // show the target
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-borderless">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="w-30">Remarks</th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-target="#demoDeets1">
        <td scope="row"><label for="" title="remark">Remark 1</label>
        </td>
        <td scope="row">
          <a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit1" class="icon-3 modalBtn">Edit</a>
          <div class="modal fade" id="edit1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <b>heading1</b>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <input type="text" class="big-input-w13h4 form-control" name="mail">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-target="#demoDeets2">
        <td scope="row"><label for="" title="remark">Remark 2</label>
        </td>
        <td scope="row">
          <a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit2" class="icon-3 modalBtn">Edit</a>

          <div class="modal fade" id="edit2" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <b>heading2</b>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <input type="text" class="big-input-w13h4 form-control" name="mail">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr data-target="#demoDeets3">
        <td scope="row"><label for="" title="remark">Remark 3</label>
        </td>
        <td scope="row">
          <a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit3" class="icon-3 modalBtn">Edit</a>

          <div class="modal fade" id="edit3" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <b>heading3</b>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <input type="text" class="big-input-w13h4 form-control" name="mail">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="modal fade" id="demoDeets1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <b>heading row modal 1</b>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="demoDeets2" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <b>heading row modal 2</b>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="demoDeets3" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <b>heading rwo modal 3</b>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

With your choice of datatable, the script does not work per row

I just completely wasted my time creating this script which SHOULD work but it does not because the crap datatable script does NOT sort the rows!!! It just replaces the cell contents.

I had to use the label in the first cell to save the row index.

```js
$(() => {
  const dataTable = new simpleDatatables.DataTable('.datatable');
  const $datatable = $('.datatable-table');
  $datatable.on('click', 'tr td', function(e) { // listen for clicks in cells
    if ($(this).find('.modalBtn').length === 0) { // only react if there is not a button
      // BUT use the button to get the row
      const editTarget = $(this).closest('tr').find('td a.modalBtn').attr('data-bs-target'); // get the data-target from row
      const target = editTarget.replace('edit', 'demoDeets');
      $(target).modal('show'); // show the target
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@latest/dist/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@latest" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-borderless datatable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="w-30">Remarks</th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr target="#demoDeets1">
        <td scope="row"><label for="" title="remark">Remark 1</label>
        </td>
        <td scope="row">
          <a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit1" class="icon-3 modalBtn">Edit</a>
          <div class="modal fade" id="edit1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <b>heading1</b>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <input type="text" class="big-input-w13h4 form-control" name="mail">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-target="#demoDeets2">
        <td scope="row"><label for="" title="remark">Remark 2</label>
        </td>
        <td scope="row">
          <a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit2" class="icon-3 modalBtn">Edit</a>

          <div class="modal fade" id="edit2" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <b>heading2</b>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <input type="text" class="big-input-w13h4 form-control" name="mail">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr data-target="#demoDeets3">
        <td scope="row"><label for="" title="remark">Remark 3</label>
        </td>
        <td scope="row">
          <a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit3" class="icon-3 modalBtn">Edit</a>

          <div class="modal fade" id="edit3" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <b>heading3</b>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <input type="text" class="big-input-w13h4 form-control" name="mail">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="modal fade" id="demoDeets1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <b>heading row modal 1</b>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="demoDeets2" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <b>heading row modal 2</b>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="demoDeets3" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <b>heading rwo modal 3</b>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The thing is rows are dynamically generated by django template. You suggested me to remove the django tag so i removed. Here in your answer you have created those modals outside the table element. but that is not the actual case. When django renders the html it creates rows by the data in context. So **demoDeets** modals must be created inside the tbody element after each tr. I have tried ```<tr data-target="#demoDeets1">``` But it didn't work so i had to improvise with js and anchor hidden 'a' tag. Now i want another modal to open by the button inside the td tag of each tr.

Comment: So fix your DJANGO since it creates invalid HTML

Comment: I cannot see why you cannot have two loops  https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/nr1mxfu2/

Comment: you right i will try that. Also if i create more button in the same td element linked to their own unique modals, will they work in the same way?

Comment: Thank you so much. Don't know why i didn't think of the second loop. Also can you explain the js used. I am still very new to jq.

Comment: Works perfectly with other buttons too. Thanks a lot. A little explanation of jq will be helpful.

Comment: You are welcome. I thought the script was pretty self explanatory with my comment

Comment: Yes I was self explanatory. But I didn't understand the syntax on first line. But then later understood that is just a way to run jq query function. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Yeah, I saw you were using () => so I just saved the `document).ready(`

Comment: Yes understood that a bit later. Thanks for the shorthand :)

Comment: Hey now when I am using datatable and click on a column header to sort the table the modal wont open on clicking the tr rows.

Comment: Look again  - You did not tell me you needed to move the rows which is why I fixed them. You should be able to sort and click now

Comment: After sorting button clicks are working, but clicking tr td modal won't open.
I am using datatables plugin on the table.

Comment: Works for me. See update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255422/discussion-between-indrajeet-singh-yadav-and-mplungjan).

Comment: For some reason this code is working properly in a different instance. Maybe the js file didn't load properly. although I have not used this line ```let table = new DataTable('.table');```. Thanks again

Comment: Ok, I really hacked this now. I use the data-bs-target from the modal button in the row to show the row modal

Comment: Yes this is working perfectly. Thanks a lot. Sorry for the trouble. But thanks to you I have better understanding of how this works. Thank you :)